# Migrating from gulp 3.0 to gulp 4.0

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulpfile

Following task doesn't run the *copyfonts* and *imagemin* tasks inside the function body. When I call them individually they work fine.

```
    gulp.task('build', gulp.series('clean', function(done){ 
         gulp.parallel('copyfonts', 'imagemin');
         done();
    }));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gulp.task('build', gulp.series('clean', gulp.parallel('copyfonts', 'imagemin'), done =>
     done();
));
```

Just move the `parallel` tasks into the `series` call directly.